# Access object methods dynamically

Tags: design-patterns, dart, getter, dart-mirrors

```
person.name // => "Chad"
var attr = "name";
person.send(attr); // => Ruby style, throws error
person[attr]; // => ECMAScript style, throws error
```

How does one do this in Dart?

---

Also, what is this idea/pattern called? Dynamic getter? Data-driven getter? Variable message/attribute to object?

Comment: In Dart this is done with mirrors. Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317924
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873896
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395799
You can find more when you click the dart-mirrors tag below your question.

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic access to properties in Dart, you need to go through the mirror system.

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

...
print(person.name);  // Chad
var name = reflect(person).getField(#name).reflectee;
print(name);  // Chad
var attr = "name";
name = reflect(person).getField(new Symbol(attr)).reflectee;
print(name);  // Chad
```

See https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-mirrors.InstanceMirror#id_getField

Comment: Is mirror system compatible with flutter obfuscation ?

Comment: Mirrors are not available on Flutter at all, so no.