# Dart dynamically access getters

Tags: flutter, dart

The generated `AppLocalizations` in flutter has many getters

```dart
final appLocalizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
print(appLocalizations.helloWorld);
```

I have a use case that the getter keys is stored in a `List<String>` and I need to translate them

```dart
const key = 'helloWorld';
print(appLocalizations[key]);
```

How I can access to the getter by a `String` variable like `key` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that as of yet. I've filed a feature request a while back, but they don't seem enthused about it.

You can follow up on it here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84326

Comment: Here is an option using mirror https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438187/6447123, But I don't like that and unsure about obfuscation

Comment: You can't use mirrors with flutter it goes against some of the tree shaking they do. So you would have to do something with code generation which I imagine would be clumsy.